# How to write a c application code to test a linux audio driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, alsa

I have an audio driver present in linux kernel that i have. Using alsa utilities like aplay, set and get i want to write a c application to test driver's functionalities like playback, set volume and get volume. I have a confusion that how to use aplay and other alsa commands in a c code. I am doing it for the very first time. Can anybody help me with the way to do achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that in C and not as a target in your makefile?

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Actually that is a requirement given to me. I am expected to provide with a very simple c code which should be able to playback, set volume and get volume using the driver using alsa. I am not getting how to do it. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer to this question:

[Set ALSA master volume from C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787318/set-alsa-master-volume-from-c-code)

And also read the alsa/mixer lib manpage.

Other references:
http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/mixer_8h.html