# Wrong VLC volume at launch after calling alsa-lib

Tags: c++, vlc, volume, alsa

I'm stuck on a problem with VLC and alsa-lib.

**The context is the following:**

- C++ app
- Run on raspberry PI
- Version: VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision
  2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
- First in the app, I set the global system volume using alsa-lib (code
  provided below)
- Fork the process to run VLC in console (cvlc)
- Set different volumes in later

**My problem is the following:**
When in run my application, if I set the volume using alsa-lib before forking and launching VLC, VLC starts with a volume higher than expacted (i.e the one I set).

If I remove the code changing the volume from my program, VLC starts with the global system volume set (I tested with a volume set to 0).

When I run VLC from the console, I get the same behavior, it starts with the global system volume currently set.

To add more precision: When I set again a different volume with the same piece of code in my program, but after having forked and launched VLC, the volume level is properly applied. As I think the problem is related to the alsa-lib call, I tried several functions in alsa-lib to release memory but it didn't solve the problem.

Here is the code I use (remove error handling to be more readable) to set the volume with alsa-lib (inspired of [Set ALSA master volume from C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787318/set-alsa-master-volume-from-c-code)):

```
// ALSA mixer handle
snd_mixer_t *m_handle;
snd_mixer_elem_t* m_elem;
long volume = -1000; // This volume is in the allowed range specified by "amixer"

// Open an empty mixer
snd_mixer_open(&m_handle), SND_MIXER_ELEM_SIMPLE);
snd_mixer_attach(m_handle, "hw:0");
snd_mixer_selem_register(m_handle, NULL, NULL);

// Load the mixer elements
snd_mixer_load(m_handle);

// Configure the simple element we are looking for
snd_mixer_selem_id_t *simpleElemId; // mixer simple element
snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&simpleElemId);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(simpleElemId, 0);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(simpleElemId, "PCM");

m_elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(m_handle, simpleElemId);

// Here is set the global system volume
snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(m_elem, volume);

snd_mixer_detach(m_handle, "hw:0");
snd_mixer_close(m_handle);
```

I check with another opened console that the volume level is properly set with alsamixer command. So I can tell that the volume is properly set before running VLC. So I don't understand why it has trouble with its volume level when starting...

Am I OK with the code calling alsa-lib? Do I forget releasing or removing an element?

Note 1 : that alsamixer shows that VLC is not modifying the global system volume when launched.

Note 2: The verbose option (-vvv) gives the same trace whatever it is launched from my C++ program (with volume problem) or from console

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was due to a bug in the Raspberry PI firmware. It has now been solved (cf. the bug report that I opened: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/570 ).

To get the last firmware, run the command:
`sudo rpi-update`

The bug was fixed in version 3.10.38+ #675 PREEMPT Sun Apr 27 18:15:12 BST 2014 armv6l

Hope this will help!