# How to do mixing of X channels into a single channel

Tags: alsa

I am newly into ALSA and linux,

How to do mixing of X channels into a single channel using ALSA plugins on record path?

and

How to control volume using alsamixer for each channel?

I am looking into http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib APIs but didnt find anything suitable, hence asked here. Please guide me to proper direction, sample code or tutorial. I too have looked on SO but i get info on play path.

Comment: You get format conversion automatically. The `softvol` plugin supports only two channels.

Comment: You would need two separate `softvol` plugins.

Comment: The `softvol` mixer control(s) can be accessed like any other mixer control.

Answer (score 1):

You need dmix plugin. 
It is quiet easy to use.
In /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.<device_name> {
   type dmix        # plugin type
   ipc_key 321456   # any unique value through /etc/asound.conf
   slave {
      pcm "hw:0,0"  # Sound card name
      format S32_LE # That is you format
      rate 44100    # Sampling rate
      channels 2    # You channels count 
   }
}
```

After restart you should be able open device  from different locations and alsa will mix their output.
Here some docs about it: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html

Comment: `dmix` has nothing to do with recording.

Comment: JRC, Yes it is suitable for any number of channels, I don't ever work with volume, but you may try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787318/set-alsa-master-volume-from-c-code

Comment: @JRC It is a separate question that should not be asked in a comment of a different question.

Answer (score 1):

First, start with a device that allows multiple recording clients:

```perl
pcm.snooped {
    type dsnoop
    slave.pcm "hw:0"  # or whatever
}
```

Then extract single channels:

```perl
pcm.channel1 {
    type route
    slave {
        pcm snooped
        channels 2
    }
    ttable [ [ 1 0 ] ]
}

pcm.channel2 {
    type route
    slave {
        pcm snooped
        channels 2
    }
    ttable [ [ 0 1 ] ]
}
```

Then put a `softvol` on each of them:

```perl
pcm.channel1_softvol {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm channel1
    control.name "Channel 1 Capture Volume"
}
pcm.channel2_softvol {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm channel2
    control.name "Channel 2 Capture Volume"
}
```

Then merge them into a single device:

```perl
pcm.mixed_with_volumes {
    type multi
    slaves {
        a { pcm channel1_softvol channels 1 }
        b { pcm channel2_softvol channels 1 }
    }
    bindings [
        { slave a channel 0 }
        { slave b channel 0 }
    ]
}
```

... and use a `plug` plugin to mix the channels together:

```perl
pcm.my_device {
    type plug
    slave.pcm mixed_with_volumes
    ttable [ [ 0.5 0.5 ] ]
}
```