# How to change volume of Speaker using Alsa library?

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa, libalsa

I am controlling volume of Speaker using Alsa amixer library on Linux.
The problem I have is that its not controlling volume in a proper scale between [0,100] percentage.This sample code I got from here
[Set ALSA master volume from C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787318/set-alsa-master-volume-from-c-code)

```
//volume.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
long volume=atoi(argv[1]);
long min, max;
snd_mixer_t *handle;
snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
const char *card = "hw:0";
const char *selem_name = "Speaker";

snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
snd_mixer_attach(handle, card);
snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
snd_mixer_load(handle);

snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid, 0);
snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);
snd_mixer_elem_t* elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid);

snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(elem, &min, &max);
snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(elem, volume * max / 100);

snd_mixer_close(handle);
}

//compiling source code
gcc volume.c -o volume -lasound

//set volume of speaker 90%
./volume 90
```

The above program is not setting up volume in proper percentage which I am passing as an argument.

Percentage given to volume program -> actual set volume

0->0

10->2

20->6

30->10

40->15

50->22

60->31

70->41

80->56

90->75

100->100

As shown above when I am setting volume between range [0,100]%,  I am getting resulted volume in different scale.Ex. for value 40 it will set volume to 15%.

How can I setup volume in proper scale between [0,100] percentage ?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a logarithmic scale. So the percentage you set is nicely converted for you so that our ears experience a linear scale.

This is the only correct way to set volume as you can read [here for example](https://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/volumecontrols.html).

Comment: So it means that behaviors given by library is correct. So how can I control volume between [0,100] logarithmic scale same as sound slider do in operating system like Ubuntu?@meaning-matters