# How to get and set volume in Linux using ALSA using C#?

Tags: c#, linux, gnome, alsa

I want to get the system volume of Linux using C# code. How to do this?

Extra Info:

-->Is there any library/dll that I can use.

-->I have come across alsa-sharp but I did not find any function regarding volume.

--> I have come across C code which but I am not familiar on how I can use that in C#.

Comment: Have you checked ALSA related .net wrappers? A google search gives me [this one](https://github.com/crojewsk/SoundIOSharp) that claims to support ALSA as a backend.

Comment: Yes, I have checked them. But they don't  have any volume function that I can use. For example, In both Alsa-Sharp and SoundIOSharp , They have imported some "SETVOLUME" function. But I **don't see any C# implementation** in their respective source code. Hence I am not able to use them

Comment: Have not tested nor downloaded the API, but looks like that API has properties that return the volumen [github search on SoundIOSharp](https://github.com/crojewsk/SoundIOSharp/search?q=Volume&unscoped_q=Volume)

Comment: I am also not sure on how can I use that, SoundIOOutStream's constructor requires a parameter which I am not sure how to use. **internal SoundIOOutStream (Pointer<SoundIoOutStream> handle)**

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but I came across this while setting up an RPi-based internet radio and the following code, which you can also find [at this git](https://gist.github.com/danielcweber/b37df9e8eb4e65c81c23d31336d2ae42), works for me.

It's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787318/set-alsa-master-volume-from-c-code/6787957#6787957) and the [native interop code from alsa-sharp](https://github.com/atsushieno/alsa-sharp/) by https://github.com/atsushieno.

Note: You might need to experiment with the "card" and "selemName" parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Alsa
{
    public sealed class VolumeControl : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly long _min;
        private readonly long _max;
        private readonly IntPtr _sid;
        private readonly IntPtr _selem;
        private readonly IntPtr _handle;
        private const string LibraryName = "libasound";

        public VolumeControl(string card = "default", string selemName = "PCM")
        {
            snd_mixer_open(ref _handle, 0);
            snd_mixer_attach(_handle, card);
            snd_mixer_selem_register(_handle, default, default);
            snd_mixer_load(_handle);

            snd_mixer_selem_id_malloc(ref _sid);
            snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(_sid, 0);
            snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(_sid, selemName);
            _selem = snd_mixer_find_selem(_handle, _sid);

            snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(_selem, ref _min, ref _max);
        }

        public void SetVolumePercent(int volume)
        {
            snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(_selem, (int)(volume * _max / 100));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
        {
            snd_mixer_selem_id_free(_sid);
            snd_mixer_close(_handle);
        }

        ~AlsaSoundOutput()
        {
            ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
        }

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_open(ref IntPtr mixer, int mode);

        [DllImport(LibraryName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_attach(IntPtr mixer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_selem_register(IntPtr mixer, IntPtr options, IntPtr classp);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_load(IntPtr mixer);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_selem_id_malloc(ref IntPtr selem);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern void snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(IntPtr selem, uint val);

        [DllImport(LibraryName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern void snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(IntPtr selem, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string value);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern IntPtr snd_mixer_find_selem(IntPtr mixer, IntPtr selem);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(IntPtr selem, ref long min, ref long max);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(IntPtr selem, int value);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern void snd_mixer_selem_id_free(IntPtr selem);

        [DllImport(LibraryName)]
        internal static extern int snd_mixer_close(IntPtr mixer);
    }
}
```