# ALSA sound element name "Master" not recognized with C program, but available from amixer

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, alsa, libalsa, pyalsaaudio

I'm working on C program that uses the ALSA sound library, and I'm trying to set the volume to a specific percentage value. I've tried to follow an implementation based on the [pyalsaaudio](https://github.com/larsimmisch/pyalsaaudio/blob/main/alsaaudio.c#L1826) library and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787957/8494794). My issue starts when I set the element name to `"Master"` I encounter the following error when running my program (attached below): `snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range: Assertion 'elem' failed`. However if I set element name to  `"PCM"` the volume range retrieval works fine, but I'm not able to set the percentage properly since the values are in a logarithmic scale and cannot figure out the transformation function (is not the dB one).

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS 64bit. Also tried in Ubuntu 23.04 64bit with same results.

Also when I run `amixer scontrols` in the terminal the output is:

```bash
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long min, max;
    snd_mixer_t *handle;
    snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
    const char *card = "default";
    const char *selem_name = "Master";

    snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
    snd_mixer_attach(handle, card);
    snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
    snd_mixer_load(handle);

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid, 0);
    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);
    snd_mixer_elem_t* elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid);

    snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(elem, &min, &max);

    long range = max - min;
    // setting the volume to 58%
    long volume = min + (range * 58/100);
    snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(elem, volume);

    printf("volume min: %ld - max: %ld\n", min, max);

}
```

I'm using the following command to compile it `gcc -o audio audio.c -lasound`

Comment: Your code works fine for me. (Ubuntu 22.04 on x86_64).

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thanks for checking! I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Rasbperry Pi OS 64 bit, updating it in the main question... It might be something regarding the OS then...

Comment: @jsgalarraga it is definitely Pi OS or Pi 4 specific. Works fine on openSUSE and Archlinux as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem. I was executing the script with sudo:

```bash
sudo ./audio
```

However the ALSA behavior is not the same as if you run it without sudo, so the solution was to run it just like:

```bash
./audio
```

The reason why I was running with sudo was because I'm also accessing to the GPIO in the same program, which requires root privileges.
In case it helps someone, the complete solution to access GPIO but run the program without sudo was to change its ownership and permissions.

```bash
sudo chown root:root audio
sudo chmod 4755 audio
./audio
```

Comment: Glad you have it figured out, but `sudo chown root:root audio`, and `sudo chmod 4755 audio` are very likely to cause problems with user access to the sound system. Depending on your OS, *consolekit* or *polkit* or *D-bus* or a combination provides user permission to sound devices. Many use an *audio* group. Changing ownership will prevent the system from providing access in many cases. Just something to keep in mind.